# Can i make Json Volley request in main thread?

Tags: android, json, multithreading

I need to make a JSON Request and set UI depending on its response, so it would nice to make it in onCreate in the same thread.

Speaking about RequestFuture, I can't reliably use it for this, or I don't know how to do it.

```
RequestFuture<JSONObject> future = RequestFuture.newFuture();
JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(URL, null, future, future);
requestQueue.add(request);

try {
  JSONObject response = future.get();
  count = response.getIn("int");
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
} catch (ExecutionException e) {
}catch (JSONException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

I tried this, but its dont work.

If someone know pls show an example how to get data from JSONObject and dont do nothing befor data is goten and than use that values to set some Views.

Comment: thx for the comment, butpls write answer with example if you can. )

Comment: pls if you put -, tell me the reason, to not repeat in future? thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as there is getActivity() in your code, i bet you are in a fragment.
to do something on UI thread you could call something like this

```
    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // your UI-related code goes here    
        }
    });
```

Comment: ok, ill try. thx. and if i wanna you this in activity it goes like this?

Comment: this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // your UI-related code goes here    
        }
    });
  or how should i do it?

Comment: i guess that it would work with this.runOnUiThread
or just call runOnUiThread without this

Comment: anyways, there are better answers as i can see. guys that use volley suggest using API provided  by the library and i'd say go for it -- use the official volley way.

Comment: but JsonArrayRequest and JsonObjectRequest are running it own thread, i tryed it, dont works in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Using Volley you have listeners of response when succeed and an error listener when server has a respone with error code (500, 401).
So you can create a JSONObjectRequest like the following code lines:

```
    JSONObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonArrayRequest
            (REQUEST_URL, new Response.Listener<JSONObjectRequest>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObjectRequest response) {
                    // this code will be executed when response comes and you can set your views, the way is depending where you are (fragment, activity, etc), you can do runOnUiThread
                    Log.d("Hello", "You can do whatever you want wen data is goten");
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.d("Error","You can show an error dialog here ");
                }
            });
```

You have to add the above object created to the HTTQueue and it will be executed at its time. Hope it helped !

Comment: y but if i whant to get value from request i can run in some null exeption couz it runs in different thread.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using volley then you can use the listeners. You can also refer this https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html . In onResponse or onError you can do the UI changes that you want.

```
JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(url, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

  @Override
  public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {


  }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {

  @Override
  public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {


    }

  }
});
```